# Refresh activity with fragments in back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, refresh, restart

I'm working on the application with multi language support. I need to be able to change application language runtime so after updating the context with new locale I need to restart the activity. This activity draws fragments so before the restart there are few fragments in back stack.

I found `recreate()` method in `Activity` class which works fine. Problem is that this method blink the screen which looks bad.

I also found another approach how to refresh an activity. This is without a blink:

```
finish()
overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
startActivity(intent)
overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
```

Problem with this is that it removes all fragments from back stack.

Is there any other approach how to refresh the activity with fragments without a blink?

Answer (score -2):

use async task 
1- use dobackground method 
2- use dopost method

Comment: I don't understand how can it help me. Can you provide sample of code.